# Loss of quality while adding subtitle via FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, conversion, compression, subtitles

After solving on problem I cam coming to a next one. After adding subtitles, discussed [here](https://video.stackexchange.com/q/17543/12686), with the command:

```
ffmpeg -i grdedFinal.mov -vf subtitles=portSbs.srt gradedFinalwithSubs.mov
```

the quality of the generated file significantly decreased. The original file was of size **1,5GB** whereas the resulting file was of size **~300MB**. The subtitles are added correctly but the compression is unnecessary. In a word I would like for the **FFmpeg** to add subtitless and do only that leaving the sound and picture quality untouched.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you are hardcoding subtitles, the video (with the subtitles added) **will be re-encoded**.

You can use the CRF rate control method to modulate the quality of the output.

So, start with

```
ffmpeg -i grdedFinal.mov -vf subtitles=portSbs.srt -crf 18 -c:a copy gradedFinalwithSubs.mov
```

If the quality's not acceptable, lower that value till it is - in exchange for a larger file. Of course, don't decide based on file *size* but on visual quality. x264 is very good at compressing video while maintaining subjectively perceived quality.

Comment: Thanks very much, I had a look [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#crf) and put `crf 0`.

Comment: Unnecessary, but that's your choice. Use edited command for audio passthrough.

Comment: So what `crf` would be optimal for lack of quality loss? Side question, the created file does not open in QuickTime but it runs in VLC so I'm guessing that the file is no longer `mov` but `avi` for example?

Comment: For being mathematically lossless? None. For being visually lossless, `18` is generally transparent, but YMMV. Try `-crf 1` - I think ffmpeg has chosen a pixel format for CRF 0 that QT doesn't work with.